# Hardhat not picking up balance after smart contract sends it

Tags: typescript, jestjs, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm trying to write tests for a smart contract I have. For simplicity this is what the smart contract looks like:

**Note:** I hardcoded the value to be 100% sure what value was leaving the contract.

```
function withdraw(uint256 tokenId, address to, address owner) external returns (uint256 amount) {
    amount = _positionManager.withdraw(tokenId, owner);
    
    _wrapper.withdraw(amount);
    //(bool success, ) = to.call{value: amount }("");
    (bool success, ) = to.call{value: 100000000000000000 }("");

    // failed transfer...
    require(success, "3FM:FT");
    emit Withdraw(to, amount);
}
```

I have test which looks like so:

```
const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();
const oldBalance = await provider.getBalance(owner.address);
console.log('Old Balance:' + oldBalance);

await fundManager.withdraw(defaultTokenId, owner.address, owner.address);
const newBalance = await provider.getBalance(owner.address);
const expectedAmount = oldBalance.add(BigNumber.from("100000000000000000"));    

console.log('New Balance:' + newBalance);
expect(newBalance).to.equal(expectedAmount);
```

When I look at the the console it says the new balance is the same as the old balance. However my smart contract doesn't throw.

I have a feeling this is related to the way hardhat works and it just ignores the values.  How can I verify that the balance is being sent properly?

**Edit:** Other information

1. I've verified my hardhat config will not silently fail, by replacing the success variable with an explicit false
2. These are the logs returned by running the test:

> Old Balance:276014338387200
> New Balance:276014338387200

3. I have a feeling this must be a hard hat issue, as no matter how much I make in my initial deposit from that same account, I am always returned with the same balance.

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue (please post minimalistic code that can be copy-pasted and results in the same error), so at least here's a few notes: 1) Depending on your Hardhat/Ethers config, the `withdraw()` function might fail silently, so the JS code continues even though the execution failed. 2) The `withdraw()` function should fail if the contract holds less than `100000000000000000` wei. Check if it really holds the amount. 3) Try wrapping the function call with `expect().to.be.reverted` and other matchers - https://hardhat.org/hardhat-chai-matchers/docs/overview#reverts

Comment: turns out it was using the wrong provider I guess it was doing a live look up instead

Answer (score 1):

The issue was this line of code:

```
const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();
```

The default provider isn't necessarily the one you're using for the test instead you need to be accessing the provider on ethers like so:

```
ethers.provider.getBalance(owner.address);
```